# Loadrunner Protocol to record and playback JSONArrays

Tags: ajax, arrays, loadrunner

I'm recording a script using loadrunner 11.52 and web\http protocol to record CRM activity.
Im using web/http because the users access the CRM package via url & browser.

I've noticed I generate a lot of web_custom_requests containing JSONArrays, I can work out what most of the arrays do. Looks like I will need edit a lot of my responses.

Is WEB\HTTP the best protocol to use in this instance, and does anyone have any tips ?

(Protocol adviser suggested Web\Http,Ajax - Click and Script & TruClient Ajax - IE)
The PC I'm using (via rdp) is IE8 so I'd need to up that to IE9 if I wanted to use 
TruClient Ajax )

Answer (score 0):

I think that you hit the ultimate question of load testing. Do I use a low level protocol which is harder to use but will give much more scalability or a high level protocol which is easier but less scaleable. I am afraid there is no concrete answer, it is based on your experience and willingness to do your job as a load tester. My advice: If you don't need thousands of virtual users and TruClient works for you (BTW, you should use TruClient FireFox if your website works in FireFox) then use TruClient otherwise you use Web/Http, it just might be worthwhile in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Buzzy, I couldn't get loadrunner to record using Truclient so looks like its web/http